# How do I display a user's previous orders as a select box option on a product?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, javascript, user-meta

I have an audio customization site (Wordpress/Woocommerce) that allows users to purchase licensed music in either an 'as-is' state or a customized version of it. The specifications of a customization are determined before the product is added to cart via monetized on-page options (eg. voiceovers, sound fx, etc).

Turns out a lot of customers don't know they want it customized until days/weeks/months after purchasing.
So I created individual products that mirror the product options so customers can still purchase them and basically 'apply them' to a previous order.

What I would like to do is to create a select box option on each of these products that calls the user's previous order numbers, so user's may specify which previous order they are applying this new purchase to.

If anyone can provide any direction on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'add_list_completed_orders' );
function add_list_completed_orders() {
    // get orders
    $orders = wc_get_orders (
        array (
            'status'        => array( 'wc-completed' ),
            'type'          => 'shop_order',
            'limit'         => -1,
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'customer_id'   => get_current_user_id(),
        )
    );

    if ( ! empty( $orders ) ) {
        // set value options
        $options = '';
        foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $order_id . '">' . $order_id . '</option>';
        }
        // add list
        $form = '<label for="orders">Select completed orders:</label>';
        $form .= '<select id="orders" name="orders">' . $options . '</select>';
        echo $form;
    }

}
```

Tested and it works. The code goes into your theme's functions.php.